# Using the given data, find the area of the required triangle in the complex plane

Tags: complex-numbers, solution-verification

> Let C be the curve $||z+3\sqrt 2|-|z-3\sqrt 2||=2\sqrt 2$. If locus of $z$ satisfying $|\text{arg} (z-1)|=\tan^{-1} (4)$ meets the curve C at points A and B, then find area of triangle ABP, where P is the point $e^{i2\pi}$

The given curve is a hyperbola with focus $(\pm 3\sqrt 2,0)$

$$\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{y^2}{16}=1$$

And for $z$

$$\frac{y}{x-1}=4$$

But the locus of $z$ is tangential to the given curve.

I think I am making a computation error or something is wrong with the signs, but I am not able to pinpoint it. Please let me know my mistake

Comment: $\left| arg(z-1)\right| = \tan^{-1}(4) \implies arg(z-1) = \pm \tan^{-1}(4)$. . . .
Now range of the function $\tan^{-1}$ is $\left[-\dfrac{\pi}2, \dfrac{\pi}2 \right]$, so the locus of $z$ is the union of two rays, one emanating from the origin in the first quadrant having slope $4$, and another emanating from the origin in the fourth quadrant having slope $-4$.